# Overloading the extraction operator

Tags: c++, file, operator-overloading

I'm overloading the extraction operator to read a node which contains a pair of numbers.

As you can see I'm printing a message for the user to know which number they are writing. However when I read from a file the messages will still print. So I want to know if there is a way to check if I'm reading from a file or from the keyboard or if there is another way to avoid printing the messages when I'm reading from a file.

Code:

```
istream &operator>>( istream &input, nod &X )
{
    cout<<"Number 1: ";
    input>>X.info1;
    cout<<"Number 2 ";
    input>>X.info2;
    X.next=NULL;
    return input;
}
```

Comment: When you overload the insertion operator it should behave the same way as it does for built in types.  You should not be asking for any input you should just be grabbing it.

Comment: You could add an overload that accepts an `fstream&`, or you could use `dynamic_cast` to check the runtime type of the stream. However, neither of these are really in the spirit of the streaming operators in C++. You shouldn't use the streaming operator to prompt for input; rather, prompt first then stream into your object. If you want to prompt between values, the best way is to read into two integers (or doubles, or whatever) first then construct an object of your custom type from those. You can then prompt for input between streaming operations, rather than within a streaming operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't interact with a user at all in the streaming operators.
That's not what they're for, and `operator>>` should just read the next object that's in the stream.

Instead, interact first and then construct the object:

```
nod read_nod()
{
    int info1 = 0;
    cout << "Number 1: ";
    cin >> info1;
    int info2 = 0;
    cout << "Number 2: ";
    cin >> info2;
    return nod(info1, info2); 
}
```

or

```
istream & operator>> (istream &input, nod &X)
{
    input >> X.info1;
    input >> X.info2;
    X.next = NULL;
    return input;
}

nod read_nod()
{
    cout << "Enter two numbers for the nod: ";
    nod n;
    cin >> n;
    return n;
}
```